# WSL ubuntu always fails with " Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)" error

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, dpkg

Trying to use ubuntu in win10 windows subsytem for linux terminal. But if I run any command, such as `sudo apt reinstall libpaper1` I get:

```
Setting up passwd (1:4.8.1-1ubuntu5.20.04.4) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/passwd.postinst: 21: getent: not found
groupadd: group 'shadow' already exists
Group ID 42 has been allocated for the shadow group.  You have either
used 42 yourself or created a shadow group with a different ID.
Please correct this problem and reconfigure with dpkg --configure passwd''.

Note that both user and group IDs in the range 0-99 are globally
allocated by the Debian project and must be the same on every Debian
system.
dpkg: error processing package passwd (--configure):
 installed passwd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 passwd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried multiple guides and apt-get install, update, upgrade, but I always get this error!

Comment: *"I've tried multiple guides ..."* - Please see if you can provide as much detail on what you have tried, along with the results.  If you've tried a lot of things already, then it's likely that someone answering will just be wasting your time (and theirs) by suggesting something you've already tried ;-).

Comment: I'm going to throw this out (and hope it's not something you've tried), but [this Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1139748/1165986) looks similar.  Since I see you are a developer (having earned some rep on Stack Overflow), is there a chance you tried to replace a system library of some sort?  If so, from what I understand from that answer you'll have to download the proper version (from the Ubuntu distribution that matches what you have installed) and manually reinstall that library using `dkpg` .

Comment: IMHO, if that is the root issue, you are probably just better off reinstalling Ubuntu under WSL and copying over any files you need.

Comment: i did fix by reinstalling ubuntu